# changing config file variable in python from other file

Tags: python

I have a file config.py and there is a variable in it balance_check  which is true by default. I have one more alltests.py  which takes certain parameters and executes other files. I want to set the value of balance_check variable to false when i am passing some particular parameter to alltests file but some how the variable does not changes for sub sequent files called from alltests.py file

Answer (score 2):

```
from ... import config

config.balance_check = False
```

This is called [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patch)

Comment: I tried this but when alltests.py is calling other python file it seems that the scope  of balance_check var ends and the value is picked from config.py file directly which is True.

Comment: you execute `alltests` file, it sets `balance_check` variable to `False` in `config` file, then call another file and in that file you use `balance_check` variable from `config` file but it is still `True`, am i right?